# Align bootstrap div below each other

Tags: jquery, html, css, blogs

Hello and thanks for reading this post.

I have this Set up using primary bootstrap and some custom css

Link to [Image](https://imageshack.us/i/exMbDJc0p)

As you can see there is a huge space between some of the post and I was wondering how I can "push" the containers of each blog up so it looks nice

Something like [this.](https://imageshack.us/i/ip5z7VDup)

**Css**

```
.blog-post-holder .well {
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center
}

.blog-post-holder .well img {
    width: 90%;
}

.blog-post-holder .well hr {
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="blog-post-holder">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">dwadwada<br />wdewad</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/blogimg1-620x350.jpg" />
                    <hr />
                    dwadwada<br />wdewad
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">dwadwada<br />wdewad</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/blogimg1-620x350.jpg" />
                    <hr />
                    dwadwada<br />wdewad
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/blogimg1-620x350.jpg" />
                    <hr />
                    dwadwada<br />wdewad
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">dwadwada<br />wdewad</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">dwadwada<br />wdewad</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="well">
                    <img src="http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/blogimg1-620x350.jpg" />
                    <hr />
                    dwadwada<br />wdewad
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have been trying for some hours now and I'm kinda lost about how I can do this. I will accept anykind of help: jquery, plugins, css or anything else.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You have to use use plugins like: http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: And another is http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/

Comment: and http://masonry.desandro.com/ ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for gridalicious  to achive this layout

http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use some available JQuery plugins like: [wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin), [Blocklist.](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/). Using  that plugins you can easily arrange like what you want.

[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is another one to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an inline display styling for inside divs, but that is not a proper solution. If you are strongly restricted to use css try this:

```
.blog-post-holder > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Otherwise use jQuery plugins suggested above. I would prefer [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) as it is easier to work with.